# Redirect after empty register form

Tags: redirect, errors, user-registration

I am trying to make a separate registration form for 2 types of users on my website: e.g. apples and oranges.

Therefore, I use the following GET requests:

- www.website.be/wp-login.php?action=register&role=apple
- www.website.be/wp-login.php?action=register&role=orange

These URLs are called when a user pushes on the respective button for registering oranges or apples and a specific registration form appears. My code also checks whether their are no empty fields. And if there are, it gives an error to the $errors variable.

Till now, everything works fine. BUT: when an error occurs (as e.g. an empty field), it plots the error information on www.website.be/wp-login.php?action=register. This means: the role specific fields are missing here!

Can someone help me how to plot the errors on the correct page (e.g. www.website.be/wp-login.php?action=register&role=apple) without erasing the completed fields?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution myself. When I adjusted the declaration of the registration form:

```
<form name="registerform" id="registerform" action="<?php echo esc_url( site_url('wp-login.php?action=register', 'login_post') ); ?>" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
```

To the following:

```
<form name="registerform" id="registerform" action="<?php echo esc_url( site_url('wp-login.php?action=register&role='.$_GET['role'], 'login_post') ); ?>" method="post"  novalidate="novalidate">
```

Then my problem is solved and the registration page is not redirected to the standard registration url.

I hope this can help other persons too.